Accidentally said אֱלֹהַי וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתַי instead of אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵֽאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ (or vice versa) - What to do?
If one mixes up the standard prayer lines brough in the title, should one correct it, or should one continue? If it depends on context, is there a principle to help guide one as to which contexts one corrects and which one continues?
Correcting it would mean saying the prayer as intended, but if that's not a me'akev difference (a difference that matters), then it might be considered unnecessarily saying Hashem's Name.

Why do you ask about this particular set of mistakes? Some reason to think it'd be different from the general case?

@DoubleAA what's the general case? Anyway, believe my second paragraph was my attempt to anticipate and answer your question :) It might not be a me'akev enough difference to warrant a repeat of Hashem's Name

in the Refa'ainu beracha in the Amish, one of my siddurim has (in the passage for adding names )  אֱלֹהַי וֵאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתַי and the other has אֱלֹהֵֽינוּ וֵֽאלֹהֵי אֲבוֹתֵֽינוּ   So I guess I can say ​either without it being a mistake.
